# Apostrophe is not properly displayed in Crouton message

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, error-message

"**You can't...**" is displayed as "**You can&#39t...**".

[image: apostrophe bug]

Version 0.1.68 (Android 4.4)

Comment: "Crouton message" - first time I ever saw this... where you came up with this term? :)

Comment: Same thing on android 4.2 (same app version)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - it's in the help page within the app. They list all of the open source libraries that are used.

Comment: @Lix yeah, looks like it's [not only for Stack Exchange app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19231596/447356) :-)

Comment: You tried to vote on your own post? ;) Good strategy to find bugs! :)

Comment: @R.J Sure, would be a huge bug if I'd be able to do this. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, I believe Android describe some of their "small popup messages" as "toast messages". This is perhaps just a translation or a similar messaging system.

Comment: @JamesWebster a "Toast" is one of those messages that comes up on the bottom/top of the screen on a black background, it's part of the real Android API, a [Crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton) is a nicer looking and behaving version of that.

Comment: I see. I'd made the link between the words, but not being an Android developer, I've used neither :P

Comment: @Kasra is there also a Fluffernutter? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in version 0.1.69 coming out later tonight, thanks!

Comment: I'm going to adopt that as a new word... That'll happen laster today :-). It's the way it happens anyway!

Comment: I need to go get more coffee..

Comment: @Kasra also, for many people night is still far far away. ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I refuse to acknowledge timezones, but when I say later tonight UTC midnight is around a good estimate